# Images don’t show in tab Vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, variables, tabs, animated-gif

I made a method « numberMatch » that push a gif, that is stored in a variable, in a tab on click. The method works well, but when i call the tab in the template instead of the gif it’s the path of the gif that shows as a string value.
Can someone tell me how to make the gif appear properly on the page instead?
The div that show the image in the tab in the template is this one:

```html
<div>{{this.gifTab}}</div>
```

```html
<script>

export default {
   name:'Body',
   data() {
       return {
           luckyNumber:'',
           randomNumber:'',
           number: 0,
           gifCharles:require("../assets/jpg/isolation-charles.png"),
           gifTab:[],
           scoresTab:[],
           total:0,
       }
   },

       methods: {
           RandomNumbGenerator(){
               this.randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
               return this.randomNumber
           },

           InputValue(){
               this.luckyNumber = document.getElementById("input_lucky_numb").value;
           },

           NumberMatch(){
               if(this.randomNumber == this.luckyNumber){
                 var tabGif = this.gifTab.push(this.gifCharles)
                 return tabGif
               }
           }
       },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an [image element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

Replace

```js
{{this.gifTab}}
```

with

```html
<img :src="gifTab"/>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it was useful! also i had to had a loop :  <div class="containerTab" v-if="gifTab && showTab">
      <div class="gifTab" v-for="gif in gifTab" :key="gif.id">
        <img class="imgGif" :src="gif" alt="gif_king" />
      </div>